# Replacing wildcard %LIKE% query

Tags: mysql

I have a file-path search, allowing a user to search his/her files on a website. Example entries are:

```
`path`
- /Volumes/Fulfill/03-01-13/FILFILE.txt
- /Volumes/Master/.Trash/Weeds.mov
```

If someone search for "master mov" it would do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE path LIKE '%master%' AND path LIKE '%mov%'
```

and would return:

```
- /Volumes/Master/.Trash/Weeds.mov
```

What would be a better way or method to do the above search?

**Update**: I tried doing the following, but my implementation of the `MYISAM FULLTEXT` search didn't work well at all:

```
select * from path where path like '%red%' and path like '%state%' <-- works
select * from path where match(path) against ('red state'); <-- zero results
```

Is there another way to implement full text search than the above?

Comment: I believe that's the best way.

Comment: You may look at [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), if your table is BIG; otherwise what you're doing now should be fast enough.

Comment: What about using MyISAM full-text search? would that help at all?

Comment: Your method is fine, but can you not do the search on the disk?  That would be a lot faster.  Also note that your query would match `/Volumes/Mov/.Trash/Weeds.master`

Comment: That's fine. No, these are volumes that aren't on the user's local computer and there are a few million files so the searches take 2-4 seconds each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% is a wildcard. It will be faster if you replace it with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM files WHERE path LIKE '/Volumes/Master%mov'
```

Because you're not checking for more conditions.

**Update**

For Full Text option you would (one time)

```
ALTER TABLE files ADD FULLTEXT(path);
```

Then for the searches you would

```
SELECT * FROM files
WHERE MATCH (path)
AGAINST ('+Master +mov' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Short words are ignored, the default minimum length is 4 characters. You can change the min and max word length with the variables ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len

Comment: Right, though the above simply would not work in the scenario I have.

Comment: Full-text is probably your best bet then.